# How to override the width and height values in scss file

Tags: css, sass

I want to override the default values in scss file like

```
.auth-form {
width: 800px;
}
```

I change the width values in **class auth-form** scss file. But it is not working.

How to override the values in scss file. Please let me know.

Comment: Overwrite what exactly? Do you have some other class that seta the height of `.auth-form`?

Comment: I want to change the width size. So i changed 500px.But it is not working.

Comment: You need to post the original css rule. The one you are trying to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Making assumptions on what will be the case you are probably facing a scope issue. If you have the following css:

```
.foo .bar {
    color: red;
}
.bar {
    color: blue;
}
```

`.bar` will always be red, because you are not overwriting the selector in the correct scope.

So in your case you need to specify the full selector:

```
.full.scope .auth-form {
    width: 800px;
}
```

Where `.full.scope` is the full selector to `.auth-form`. You can get the full selector using on the css you eqnt to overwrite using the browser inspector.

Another option will be to make the property prioritary using the  `!important` css keyword so it will overwrite any previous definition:

```
.auth-form {
    width: 800px !important;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`.scss` (sass) files are not directly loadable into browsers, they need to be compiled to `.css` files first, then those are loaded into browsers by your application.

It seems you are not performing the compilation step (also called preprocessing or precompiling) and this is the reason you do not see the modification in your app.

How the compilation should be done varies. You may use sass directly (see [here](https://sass-lang.com/guide)) or if you are using a framework there may be tools that combine this and other automation steps. For instance in Ruby-on-Rails you would install the required compile tool in the form of a gem and run:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

As you do not provide details on your environment / framework is is difficult to provide the exact procedure applicable to you.